# What is omitted from the current Western, Catholic Psalter?

Tags: catholicism, psalms, liturgy-of-the-hours

I know that there are at least two Pslams omitted from the current Breviary, and I know that some pieces of others are missing (Psalm 136, for example, is missing the verse about dashing baby's skulls against rocks). I can't seem to find a reference to *which* Psalms and which verses are omitted.

Comment: Are you sure Ps 110 has that verse? Or did you mean Ps 136/137, where it's v9? And which numbering system? And, indeed, which psalter? (The Breviary uses the Grail Psalter, which is complete)

Comment: @AndrewLeach You're right. I was thinking of the line "He will judge the nations, heaping up the dead and crushing the rulers of the whole earth" which is also omitted. I'll change the word to "Breviary" because there are decidedly omissions.

Comment: OK: So you're saying that the Breviary customarily omits verses from the selection of psalms it uses, and you want to know which ones? Might be another question for Martin Kochanski!

Comment: Can you provide a link, or other *specific* identifying information for "the current Brevairy?"  "Current" is an ever-changing target--perhaps a publishing date, at minimum, would be helpful?

Comment: @Flimzy http://www.catholiccompany.com/liturgy-hours-set-4-leather-i21748/

Comment: So it's the Liturgy of the Hours as published in the US in July 1999 (it may be subtly different in other territories). Perhaps you could include an example *along the lines of* "Terce on the Wednesday of Week 23 uses Psalm 136/137 but only the first six verses, as I quote here..." because that will **show** exactly what's happening and make further research easier as it will also show exactly which version of the psalter is being used.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The following is a list of omitted verses and Chapters from the four week plaster, currently in use. It follows modern numbering. Not Septuagint numbering.

**Psalms Omitted Completely:**

- Psalm 58
- Psalm 83
- Psalm 109

---

**Verses Omitted from Particular Psalms:**

- Psalm 5: 11
- Psalm 21: 9-13
- Psalm 28: 4-5
- Psalm 31: 18-19
- Psalm 40: 15-16
- Psalm 54: 7
- Psalm 55: 16
- Psalm 56: 8
- Psalm 69: 23-29
- Psalm 72: 20
- Psalm 79: 6-7,12
- Psalm 110: 6
- Psalm 137: 7-9
- Psalm 139: 19-22
- Psalm 140: 10-12
- Psalm 141: 10
- Psalm 143: 12

---

*Source: [Psalms and Verses Omitted from the Four-Week Psalter](http://catholic-resources.org/LoH/Psalter-Omissions.html)  Compiled by Fr. Felix Just, S.J., Ph.D.*

Answer (score 0):

Which Psalter specifically are you talking about? The Monastic Breviary? Roman Breviary (and which one specifically?) or the *Novus Ordo* Breviary (which uses the *Nova Vulgata* for its Psalter)?

As far as I am aware there is nothing missing; the whole point of praying the entire Psalter every week was to pray the full 150 psalms together.

Everything was included in the past; it was tradition to pray the entire 150 psalms. Now, granted some psalms were only prayed once, while some others might have been repeated. There were some weeks due to several festivities that they would not all be prayed, but this was largely restored after Leo XIII by re-fixing only very specific Saints who had a higher ranking. This was largely done in the Roman Breviary because this was never really a problem in the Monastic Breviary.

You can see the various versions of the Divine Office from pre-Tridentine all the way up to the "1960 Newcalendar" version [here](http://www.divinumofficium.com/cgi-bin/horas/officium.pl).